# How to tell if a textbox passed validation using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-validate

I am using asp.net, mvc3, EFCodeFirst and jquery.  I want to generate images dynamically based on 'validated' input from a textbox (based on an event firing when the textbox passes validation)

ex. 
user inputs '3' and 3 images appear.
user inputs 'a' and nothing happens because it fails validation.

What event should I subscribe to on the textbox?

My model:

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Please input how many cells to create")]
[Range(5, 100, ErrorMessage = "Cells needs to be between 5 and 100")]
public int CellsPerGeneration { get; set; }
```

My view:

```
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <td>
        @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.CellsPerGeneration, new { id="numOfCells" })
    </td>
```

All I need to know is what event to reference in my script.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`invalidHandler` is what you need, i think.

eg

```
$("#Form").validate({
    invalidHandler: function (form, validator) {
    ...
    ... 
   }
});
```